# `hyperref` does not jump to the correct location of the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, tocloft

I use the following syntax to add the bibliography of a chapter as a section

`\defbibheading{bibliography}{\section{References for \chaptername\space\thechapter}}`

However, the above syntax will add the references as a normal section which would include the numbering. I would like the section numbering to be empty. Thus, I try to use

```
\defbibheading{bibliography}{%
    % Generate the heading
    \section*{References for \chaptername\space\thechapter}
    % Add it to the TOC (without adding the section number)
    \addtocontents{toc}{
            \protect \contentsline{section}{\protect\numberline{}\noindent References for \chaptername\space\thechapter}{\thepage}{page.\thepage}
                    }
                        }
```

`hyperref` will then jump to the correct page of the references but not to the exact location of the added section. I want the link to behave exactly as when using the unstarred version of `\section` but without including the section number for the references section.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
@article{aldaoudeyeh2016,
    title={{Photovoltaic-battery scheme to enhance PV array characteristics in partial shading conditions}},
    author={Aldaoudeyeh, Al-Motasem},
    journal={IET Renewable Power Generation},
    volume={10},
    number={1},
    pages={108--115},
    year={2016},
    publisher={IET}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\usepackage[style=ext-numeric, maxnames=5, minnames=1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\defbibheading{bibliography}{%
    % Generate the heading
    \section*{References for \chaptername\space\thechapter}
    % Add it to the TOC (without adding the section number)
    \addtocontents{toc}{
            \protect \contentsline{section}{\protect\numberline{}\noindent References for \chaptername\space\thechapter}{\thepage}{page.\thepage}
                    }
                        }

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents



\chapter{New Chapter}

\blindtext 

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: *biblatex does not seem to support automatic addition of the bibliography to the TOC.* Yes, it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`biblatex` *does* support adding the bibliography to the TOC. Have a look at the `heading` option to `\printbibliography`. You probably want `heading=subbibintoc`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage[style=ext-numeric, maxnames=5, minnames=1]{biblatex}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{New Chapter}
\blindtext

\nocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography[title=References for \chaptername\space\thechapter, heading=subbibintoc]
\end{document}
```

[image: TOC entry]

---

Your definition didn't quite link to the correct place because the link label was set to `page.\thepage`, whereas you probably want it to go directly to the section anchor, that's why I would use `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{...}` instead.

The definition of `\addsec` is taken from `\defbibheading{subbibintoc}` for the `book` class in `biblatex.def` (the command name is taken from KOMA-Script, which provides a command which does roughly the same thing, but with more sophistication)

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\addsec}[1]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
  \if@twoside\markright{\abx@MakeMarkcase{#1}}\fi}
\makeatother

\defbibheading{bibliography}{%
  \addsec{References for \chaptername\space\thechapter}}
```

Comment: This addresses what I want. However, I want the default heading when using `\printbibliography` to be `subbibintoc`. Also, the title must automatically be set to `References for \chaptername\space\thechapter` for each `subbibintoc` heading. This is because I just want to type `\printbibliography` and let LaTeX handle the rest

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh See the edit, please.